# Logisim Adder Circuit

Tags: adder, logisim

[image]

I was trying to add 0xA5 and 0x44 by using adder circuit and connect Hex Digit Display to show. however, the Hex Digit Display doesn't show me anything and the result also not right. i would appreciate any help!Thanks

Comment: The whole picture looks like a mess. The red color on a wire/bus is a clear indication of a problem, I think. And I see other problems there, as well. I never bothered with any study of the docs on Logisim and somehow have had zero problem using Logisim, corrrectly and well. For me, it's intuitive. But I think it's not, for you. You need some help. Put your files somewhere so that others can load them and show you how to correct them.

Answer (score 0):

Soo many things wrong with this circuit:
1: You "connected" a cable on top of the hex display, the input is in bottom and bottom only

2: There are 2 inputs to a wire connecting to the final hex display

3: hex displays display 4 bits, not 8. Split the 8 bits in 2 halfes and connect them seperately

4: C_out output pin is not connected

5: C_in is not connected and pin is an output, not an input

6: Input pins have 1 output and not on any side nor any position